# Will there be noticeable vignetting with 86mm filter ring stepped down to 82mm?

Tags: lens, filters, filter-diameter

I'm about to buy a Meike 8mm Cine Lens for my BMPCC 4k (which has a 2.0x crop factor) in the M43 mount variant. The filter thread size is 86mm, but my only Pro-Mist and ND filter thread sizes work with 82mm.

If I use a step-down ring, how noticeable will the vignetting be? Or there will be none?

Answer (score 1):

I know that several of the Meike lenses for 4/3 actually cover APS, so it's quite possible there will be no vignetting. Mechanical vignetting is very dependent on the aperture used... if there is vignetting I would suspect it will probably be eliminated by f/5.6.

But IDK anyone who has tried the 8mm on APS or w/ 82mm filters.

Comment: The lens aperture starts at 2.9

Comment: I'm aware... stopping down eliminates that type of vignetting

Answer (score 0):

Particularly at wide apertures, it is common for wide angle lenses to vignette. The lens may have vignetting already.

Trying the combination is only way to tell if the results are acceptable to you.